# OnConguring() & AddDbContext()

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1, ef-core-2.2

I'm trying to play with Entity Framework Core. So, during the course. I scafolded my existing DataBase Objects.
So, application generated the EmployeeContext.cs file with all the DBSet objects. And Upon that it generated the OnConfiguring() overloaded method.

And now I added the below code in
 **Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                //options.AddPolicy("RequireManagerOnly", policy =>
                //       policy.RequireRole("Manager"));

                options.AddPolicy(
                    "ApiUser", policy =>
                    policy.Requirements.Add(
                          new ApiUserVerification(5)));
            });
            services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler,
              ApiRoleHandler>();

            var connectionStrings = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnections");
            services.AddDbContext<EmployeeContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionStrings));
}
```

**EmployeeContext.cs**

```
public EmployeeContext()
{
}

public EmployeeContext(DbContextOptions<EmployeeContext> options)
    : base(options)
{
}


protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
#warning To protect potentially sensitive information in your connection string, you should move it out of source code. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=723263 for guidance on storing connection strings.
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("server details");
            }
        }
```

But now, when I commented the OnConfiguring() overloaded method in the context class, and posting a get request from POSTMAN, I'm getting 500-Internal Server Error. If I uncomment the OnConfiguring(), I'm able to post the request.
I don't understand why? Though I registered the DbContext in Startup.cs

Could anyone provide where I'm missing.

Thank you

Comment: You are saying EmployeeContext.cs but then you are using AddDbContext<Employee>. Is this the correct name of the class?

Comment: @AntoniosKatopodis Updated the post with actual code. My question is when I scafoled I got two EmployeeContext constructor. Could you explain why?

Answer (score 2):

Hi you can read more about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/connection-strings

In short if your working with Universal Windows Platform (UWP), you would use the:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
```

to setup your DBContext.

But since your using AspNet Core, it is good practice to have all setup in the Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
```

if you don't delete this code:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
#warning To protect potentially sensitive information in your connection string, you should move it out of source code. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=723263 for guidance on storing connection strings.
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("server details");
            }
        }
```

it will override the setup you did in startup.cs and use "optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("server details");" as your connection string.

You might have done a typo in your startup aswell.

```
services.AddDbContext<Employee>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionStrings));
```

should perhaps be:

```
services.AddDbContext<EmployeeContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionStrings));
```

Comment: I have removed the code inside OnConfiguring(), and I ran the project. It's not even post the request from POSTMAN, instead I am getting 500 error

Comment: What exception are you getting?

Comment: `InvalidOperationException: No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring method or by using AddDbContext on the application service provider. If AddDbContext is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions<TContext> object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.`

Comment: Seem you may have a typo in startup: services.AddDbContext<EmployeeContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionStrings)); You wrote Employee instead of EomployeeContext